# Android Studio - Gradle implementation (...) { exclude ... } not working (Can't exclude a group from a dependency)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, exoplayer, geckoview

I have added the below two libraries (`ExoPlayer` and `GeckoView`) to my Android App in Android Studio:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.1'
    implementation ('org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-beta:73.0.20200109090448')
    ...
}
```

When I started building the project, I realized that these libraries have conflicts together (the Gradle Sync was successful):

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.11.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.1) and jetified-geckoview-beta-73.0.2020...-runtime.jar (org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-beta:73.0.202001...)
Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.... found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.11.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.1) and jetified-geckoview-beta-73.0.2020...-runtime.jar (org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-beta:73.0.2020...)
```

I got so many lines of error like the above. So I decided to exclude the `ExoPlayer` group from the `GeckoView` (because I already have that):

```
...
implementation ('org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-beta:73.0.20200109090448') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer2', module: 'jetified-geckoview-beta-73.0.20200109090448-runtime.jar'
}
...
```

I synced again (the Sync was successful again) and started building, but no effects, the errors occurred again.

What should I do?

Comment: Hey, any updates on this? I've stumbled upon same issue lol

Answer (score -1):

From the duplicate message, the issue is that the classes are found *in* the `geckoview-beta` runtime jar itself and *in* the `exoplayer` jar as well.

So this is not a conflict of transitives, but a direct conflict between `geckoview-beta` and `exoplayer`.

You will have to resolve this by removing one of the two libraries or finding a version of `geckoview-beta` that does not embed the classes in `com.google.android.exoplayer2` package.

Comment: I can't downgrade the GeckoView or remove one of the two libraries. Any other ways?